# Errors declaring variables in stored procedure?

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I'm sort of new to SQL and stored procedures. I'm trying to set some variables to use later on in a transaction while also setting a rollback variable on an exception, but I'm not able to do this.

I don't know where the error is because when I switch the `how_many` section after the `_rollback`, The error changes.

What's wrong with the way I'm declaring variables here?

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `do_thing` $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `do_thing`()
BEGIN
        DECLARE how_many INT;
        SELECT COUNT(*) FROM things INTO how_many;
        -- Prepare roleback.
        DECLARE `_rollback` BOOL DEFAULT 0;
        DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION SET `_rollback` = 1;
        -- Start transaction.
        START TRANSACTION;
                -- Do all the things.
        IF `_rollback` THEN
                ROLLBACK;
        ELSE
                COMMIT;
        END IF; 
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

EDIT:

when I declare variables like this:

```
    DECLARE how_many INT;
    -- Prepare roleback.
    DECLARE `_rollback` BOOL DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION SET `_rollback` = 1;
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tiers INTO how_many;
```

It seems to be fine. Am I not allowed to declare more variables after certain variables in a procedure are set?

Comment: What is the error?  I don't think you should have backticks around your procedure variable names.

Comment: It just says there's an syntax exception. I actually got it working, but am not sure why. I'll edit my question.

Comment: You can't declare variables after you start code sections, meaning non-declares. That is my experience

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Manual Page [DECLARE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/declare.html):

> DECLARE is permitted only inside a BEGIN ... END compound statement
>   and must be at its start, before any other statements.
>         Declarations must follow a certain order. Cursor declarations must appear before handler declarations. Variable and condition
>   declarations must appear before cursor or handler declarations.

Note that these are called **Local Variables** in mysql. These differ from User Variables (prefixed with the `@` symbol), which can be sprinkled about with your statements and do not require a DECLARE.

Answer (score 2):

The `DECLARE` statements are only permitted after `BEGIN`, if you try to add another `DECLARE` after that it shows error.

Move the line `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM things INTO how_many;` after all `DECLARE` lines.

```
    DELIMITER $$
    DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `do_thing` $$
    CREATE PROCEDURE `do_thing`()
    BEGIN
            DECLARE how_many INT;
            -- Prepare roleback.
            DECLARE `_rollback` BOOL DEFAULT 0;
            DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION SET `_rollback` = 1;
            -- Start transaction.
            START TRANSACTION;
            SELECT COUNT(*) FROM things INTO how_many;

                    -- Do all the things.
            IF `_rollback` THEN
                    ROLLBACK;
            ELSE
                    COMMIT;
            END IF; 
    END $$
    DELIMITER ;
```